# Etherealness with extended spell for infinite life?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer

if a sorcerer casts Etherealness and uses the extended spell metamagic to extend it to 16 hours, and then after the spell ends, casts and extends it again instantly, afterward takes a long rest and repeats, is this a way too "not age" except for the 6 seconds every day?

Comment: Where are they sleeping, given that you can only benefit from a long rest once every 24 hours?

Comment: Why do you think this would or might extend the life of the caster? If feel like I'm missing a step somewhere

Comment: What makes you think you don't age while on the Ethereal Plane? As far as I'm aware, it still has time, the same as the Prime.

Comment: Are you mixing up the Ethereal with the Astral Plane?  I know creatures on the Astral Plane don't age, as specified in the DMG.

Comment: I'm stupid, I got the Astral and Ethereal mixed up

Comment: @Aydens this is one of the reasons for including the source of why you think something works a certain way :)

Comment: Adding the source is also a step that may give you enough information to not need to ask the question. It's a research effort step

Answer (score 4):

#### Not aging is a property of the Astral Plane, not the Ethereal Plane.

In the *Dungeon Master's Guide* descirption of the Astral Plane, we see:

> Creatures on the Astral Plane don’t age or suffer from hunger or thirst.

Reviewing the DMG description of the Ethereal Plane, the Ethereal Plane has no such property.